# How to validate environment variables with crc between u-boot and linux userspace?

Tags: linux, u-boot

I'm setting up a update system for a beaglebone board. In order to achieve a validation on boot, I need to be able to modify u-boot environment variables on linux.

To do that, I use fw_printenv and set_env provide by the yocto project.

When I try to read or write u-boot env on linux, I get the following error: Warning: Bad CRC, using default environment.

If I save the env on linux and reboot, I get the same error on u-boot prompt.

I can disable CRC verification on u-boot but that's not the objective.

How can I synchronize the two CRC?
Do I need to compile u-boot and fw-utils always together?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You've not configured the userspace side of things to know where to find the environment and so in Linux it's giving you the default values, and when you write you're corrupting the real values.  When you get into U-Boot it detects that you now have a corrupt environment and uses the defaults.

Comment: I use the file fw_env.config to set the config with the following : /mnt/uboot/uboot.env            0x0000         0x4000. It match what u-boot do when it save the env.